# Is there any way to inspect RabbitMQ messages that are persisted? Where those are stored?

Tags: rabbitmq

Just doing some testing on local machine, would like somewhere to inspect messages that are published and persisted by RabbitMQ (`deliveryMode = 2`). Or at least to have a time when messages was actually persisted. First try was RabbitMQ admin management, went trough all options and closest what i have found is following:

`Database directory:    /usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost`

There i can found many files with `rdq` extenstions and many logs file, but can't actually see nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't, RabbitMQ uses a custom database and it is **not** possible to browse it.

you can only browse the RabbitMQ definitions as "queues", "users", "exchanges" etc.. but not the messages.

By default, the messages index is inside:

`/usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost/queues/HASHQUEUE`

The only way it is as suggested by @Johansson

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to manually inspect your message in the queue via the Management interface. Press on the queue that has the message, and then "Get message". If you mark it as "requeue", RabbitMQ puts it back to the queue in the same order.

https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-27-part3-rabbitmq-for-beginners_the-management-interface.html

Comment: I would like to inspect persisted message, to see time of persisting and stuff like that. I dont want to consume message from the queue manually via management interface